# Wordpress Left join

Tags: wordpress, left-join

I have two table 'wp_user_reviews' and 'wp_users'.In both table 'wp_user_id' and 'id' are same..i need to take all values from first table and take'display_name' from second table.

```
    wp_user_table   
        id |wp_user_id   | user_email    |
        1  |  12         | de@gmail.com  |
        2  |  12         | de@gmail.com  | 
        3  |  13         | er@gmail.com  |

    wp_user 
        id |display_name 
        12 |  john         
        12 |  john        
        13 |  qwe         

Need to apply join query in wordpress..please help
```

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [ask], [mcve] & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also since you are a beginner read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Explain what you tried & what parts you could do or what similar thing you can do & why you are stuck. PS "take all values from first table and take'display_name' from second table" do not explain what you want. They are not clear. Use enough words & sentences to clearly say what you mean. Also why do you say you need a (left?) join if you don't know what using it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just sql request, you can do this:

```
SELECT wu.display_name FROM wp_user wu INNER JOIN wp_user_table wut ON wut.wp_user_id = wu.id;
```

If you need the PHP code for call request in WordPress:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT wu.display_name FROM wp_user wu INNER JOIN wp_user_table wut ON wut.wp_user_id = wu.id");
```

It's ok for you? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to use Left join as some users might not have given reviews.

Thus to display all info including reviews from both tables for users who have provided reviews, you can use below query

```
select * from wp_user_reviews ur LEFT JOIN wp_users u on u.id = ur.wp_user_id
```